# Vue JS - Accesing third party POST Data in my app

Tags: post, vue.js, redirect, vue-router

I am working on a Vue JS application where I am consuming a third party service for financial transaction. The service provider sends the **encrypted data** in the **body** of **POST** method as **FormData** and **redirects to my URL**. How to I access the encrypted data in my Vue JS app?

I have vue-router configured in my app. But I could only access the query or params through this.$route method.

Answer (score 1):

If the redirection is a 301/302, then it issues a GET to your page thus you can't get to the body (as GETs don't have bodies). If you have the server issue a 307, it should redirect a POST which, depending on your back-end, will give you the post. Do you have control over the redirection?